# Insert a line above a Word table at the top of the page

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

I created a table. The table is beginning at the first line of the Document. My Problem is that i cant insert a line above the table. Everytime i try to add a Paragraph, the Paragraph gets inserted after the last table. Is there a way to insert the lin above the first table?

To illustrate my Problem:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/insert-a-line-above-a-word-table-at-the-top-of-the-page/846

My Code so far:

```
Dim oApp As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document


    oApp = CType(CreateObject("Word.Application"), Word.Application)
    oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add()


    Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Range(0, 0)
    rng.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    rng.Font.Size = 16


    Dim para As Word.Paragraph = oDoc.Paragraphs.Add()
    para.Range.Text = "Factsheet"



    Dim tlb6 As Word.Table = oDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=4)


    Dim CurrentDateTime As Date = Date.Now
    Dim CurrentDate As Date = New Date(CurrentDateTime.Year, CurrentDateTime.Month, CurrentDateTime.Day)

    tlb6.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Date"
    tlb6.Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray20
    tlb6.Cell(1, 1).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
    tlb6.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = CurrentDate
    tlb6.Cell(1, 2).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
    tlb6.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Issued by"
    tlb6.Cell(1, 3).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray20
    tlb6.Cell(1, 3).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
    tlb6.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = ""
    tlb6.Cell(1, 4).Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Word 2010, this should do the job (although it is ugly and uses Select and ActiveDocument):

```
If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    tbl6.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Collapse direction:=wdLeft
    Selection.SplitTable
End If
```

It checks to make sure the first Paragraph object is inside a table, and if it does, it adds a row of text above it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That inserted a line above the table. But i have still the Problem that the Paragraph is inserted after the last table.  I dont know why...

Comment: Is having that extra paragraph a problem?  I can't reproduce this on my end - there's always a line after my last table, and nothing is added at the end when I run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kevin's answer a little cleaner solution:

```
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak
End If
```